# Add a Libraries folder in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, expo

I'm trying to add bluetooth to an app and use react native BLE plx. I used Expo so I detached my app.
In react native BLE plx [page](https://reactnativeexample.com/react-native-bluetooth-low-energy-library/), in the install process, they say:

```
Move BleClient.xcodeproj located in .node_modules/react-native-ble-plx/ios
using drag & drop to Libraries folder in your project.
```

The problem is that I don't have a "Libraries" folder in Xcode.
Do you know how to add it ? (I tied to use react-native link react-native-ble-plx it did'nt make it)

Answer (score 0):

You can add it directly to your Podfile. For example

```js
pod 'React',
    :path => "../node_modules/react-native",
    :inhibit_warnings => true,
    :subspecs => [
      "BleClient",
      ...
    ]
```

And finally run pod install in the ios folder.